# Get chatbot message logs from Azure bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I build a chatbot with MS Bot Framework composer and published it on Azure. I embedded the bot in a webpage. When I tested the bot with the emulator, I could see a log of all the messages that were sent back and forth between the user and the bot. I need a log file of all the messages while the bot is hosted on Azure.

I also activated Azure Insights. But I couldn't find a tool to extract all the messages from the conversations with the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Composer, the easy built in way is to just setup blob storage and configure transcript logging in the bots settings:

```json
{
  "runtimeSettings": {
    "features": {
      "blobTranscript": {
        "connectionString": "<CONNECTIONSTRING>",
        "containerName": "<CONTAINERNAME>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to extract all messages from the conversations with your bot hosted on Azure, you can use **write directly to storage** method.

First, you'll need to set up either an Azure Blob Storage account or an Azure Cosmos DB account and configure your bot to use it as the storage.

For Azure Blob Storage, follow these steps:

1. Create a Blob Storage account and a container in the Azure portal.
2. Add the Blob Storage configuration information (connection string and container name) to your bot's configuration file.
3. Install the necessary packages (`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Blobs`) and modify your bot's code to use Azure Blob Storage instead of Memory Storage.

For Azure Cosmos DB, follow these steps:

1. Create a Cosmos DB account and a database in the Azure portal.
2. Add the Cosmos DB configuration information (endpoint, auth key, database ID, and container ID) to your bot's configuration file.
3. Install the necessary packages (`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure`) and modify your bot's code to use Azure Cosmos DB instead of Memory Storage.

For detailed examples, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#memory-storage)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation. The problem with this solution was, that I built the bot with the composer. Hence, I couldn't figure out how to modify my code to use Azure Blob Storage instead of Memory Storage.